# webpack live reload is not working with @angular/cli

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I bought a template that uses angular, followed the setup steps but on making changes there was no live reloading. The project uses webpack too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After searching around, I found the [discussion at the official angular cli github page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1610#issuecomment-284587307) that has the solution. When running the server include the poll option i.e `ng serve --poll=2000`